# Necesito usar el resultado de una funcion fuera de si misma en js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

```
var vibrant = require("node-vibrant");

var imgSrc = './01.jpg';

vibrant.from(imgSrc).getPalette(function x(err, palette){
    var paletteResult = palette.Vibrant.getHex();
    console.log(paletteResult);
});

console.log(paletteResult);
```

en el primer `console.log` me arroja el resultado correcto, pero en el segundo me dice que no esta definida.

Comment: `paletteResult` solo esta declarada dentro de `getPalette(function x(err, palette){` por lo que fuera de esa función no existe y por eso arroja el error

Comment: Y hay alguna forma de utilizarla fuera?

Comment: Por otra parte te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio y ademas así obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Podrias intentar declarar la variable debajo de `var imgSrc = './01.jpg';` `var paletteResult = ''` y luego dentro de la función la usarías `paletteResult = palette.Vibrant.getHex();`

Comment: Me arroja undefined... :c

Answer (score 0):

Prueba declarando paletteResult también de manera global

```
var vibrant = require("node-vibrant");

var imgSrc = './01.jpg';
var paletteResult;

vibrant.from(imgSrc).getPalette(function x(err, palette){
    paletteResult = palette.Vibrant.getHex();
    console.log(paletteResult);
});

console.log(paletteResult);
```

Comment: me arroja undefined... :c

Comment: seguro que `var paletteResult` fuera de todo y `paletteResult` son reconocidas como la misma variable?

Comment: si, son las mismas, pero arroja lo mismo...

Comment: me refería a que si las esta reconociendo como la misma o a cada una le esta dando un contexto distinto @AnonymousUser

Comment: Osea si me explico lo que quiero es que la variable que esta dentro de la funcion la pueda usar fuera de ella y me arroje el mismo resultado...

Answer (score 0):

`.getPalette()` es un método asíncrono que devuelve una `Promise`, por lo que cuando estás comprobando su valor en la última línea, ese valor aún no está definido.

Si necesitas esperar a que `paletteResult` tenga un valor, podrías envolver tu código en una función asíncrona con await. Algo como esto:

```
var vibrant = require("node-vibrant");

async function((){

    var imgSrc = './01.jpg';
    var palette = await vibrant.from(imgSrc).getPalette();
    var paletteResult = palette.Vibrant.getHex();
    console.log(paletteResult)

})();
```

De todas formas, si echas un vistazo a la [documentación](https://github.com/akfish/node-vibrant#usage), verás un par de ejemplos de cómo utilizar estos métodos.